# How to log medication for past days in the Health app?

Tags: health.app

The title pretty much says it all: In the Health app, how do I to add medication for past days?

When you press “Log”, you can only select the time, not the date.

I have tried navigating to the day in question and pressing “Log”, but even then, the record will be added to the current date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of first selecting the medication and then navigating to the day you want to log the medication, you need to first select the date in question and then, under "Log", either select the scheduled medication or another one via "As-needed Medication". You can still only select the time, but it will be added to the day you previously selected.

tl;dr select the date first, then the medication (not vice versa).

Comment: Thanks for this! It makes sense now, but the ui made me think logging in the past wasn’t possible.